# combining two .bat files Dos and T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, dos, batch-file

What I would like is to combine the two files into one bat file but currently sqlcmd stops with the sqlqcmd  prompt and the SQL is not running.

Ouch server went bang so I need to put contingency in place PDQ

I normally use SQL server agent with some jobs but while the new server is being sorted.  I only have SQL express No SQL server agent.

Fine my so I have created a backup.bat it works fine in cmd calling backup.sql the sql send it to another drive.

The statement I used is:-

Sqlcmd –S \mypc\instancename –i C:\backup.sql( as I am local window authentication is fine)

This is so that i can use task scheduler in not very friendly windows 7

At the moment I have a .bat file calling a .sql file.

**Backup.bat**

```
Sqlcmd –S \mypc\instancename –i C:\backup.sql
```

**Backup.sql**

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Northwind] TO  DISK = N'\\nas1\backup\northwind.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'Northwind-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
declare @backupSetId as int
select @backupSetId = position from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'Northwind' and backup_set_id=(select max(backup_set_id) from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'Northwind' )
if @backupSetId is null begin raiserror(N'Verify failed. Backup information for database ''Northwind'' not found.', 16, 1) end
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM  DISK = N'\\nas1\backup\Northwind.bak' WITH  FILE = @backupSetId,  NOUNLOAD,  NOREWIND
GO
```

What I want is to combine the two files into one bat file but currently sqlcmd stops with the sqlcmd  prompt and the SQL is not running.

```
Sqlcmd –S \mypc\instancename  
BACKUP DATABASE [Northwind] TO  DISK = N'\\nas1\backup\northwind.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT,  NAME = N'Northwind-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
declare @backupSetId as int
select @backupSetId = position from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'Northwind' and backup_set_id=(select max(backup_set_id) from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'Northwind' )
if @backupSetId is null begin raiserror(N'Verify failed. Backup information for database ''Northwind'' not found.', 16, 1) end
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM  DISK = N'\\nas1\backup\Northwind.bak' WITH  FILE = @backupSetId,  NOUNLOAD,  NOREWIND
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found using two files works

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
quit
```

as the last line of the .SQL files.

Comment: This would only finish the sql statement not force the sql into the dos window after the sqlcmd prompt has started? which is what I am after.

Comment: I have not found the answer but I am using to files it works! but not clinical